# how to cropping video publisher date and the number of subscriber from channel publisher

Tags: python, youtube, request, beautifulsoup

I try to make a software for cropping some information from a website in specify is youtube, with a intention for make a statistics app.

I want to ask you how is the best way to get the publisher date from a youtube's video and how i cold get the number of subscriber from a youtube channel?

I was trying by this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import html5lib


g_data_subscriber = soup.find('span', 'deemphasize style-scope yt-formatted-string').get_text()

print g_data_subscriber

g_data_date = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "date"})

for item in g_data_date:
    print item.text
```

Comment: cr**o**pping. I guess you're not a native speaker, but please do google what the verb you originally used means; it's a bit funny. (I *think* you mean "to crop". I don't really think it fits here, either. Maybe you mean something like "to extract"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this can be done several different ways. I wrote some code that works for this in Python 3.5. I first go to the youtube channel url to get subscriber count. Then in the next block I go to a video url to get the "published on" date.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#get exact subscriber count from a channel
channel_name = "FirstWeFeast"
channel_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/' + channel_name
r  = requests.get(channel_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
subscriber_count = soup.find('span', 'yt-subscription-button-subscriber-count-branded-horizontal subscribed yt-uix-tooltip').get_text()
print(subscriber_count)

#get video publish date
video_url  = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCEG4QyQbF4'
r  = requests.get(video_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
date_info = soup.find('strong', 'watch-time-text').get_text()
publish_date = date_info.replace("Published on ", "")

print(publish_date)
```